# Is there any advantage to using a hard-link on ZFS instead of relying upon deduplication when considering only disk space allocation?

Tags: filesystems, zfs, hard-link, deduplication

If I want to create multiple instances of a file on a ZFS file system, is there any advantage to using a hard-link instead of relying upon deduplication as a method of preserving disk space?

This would be for archival purposes where it makes sense to have the same file appear in multiple locations for organizational relationships. It is assumed that these files will never be modified so the advantage of a hard-link updating every other instance when any one is modified is irrelevant.

This question is purely focused on whether or not there is any advantage to using hard-links to reclaim space taken up by duplicate files.

Answer (score 2):

The main advantage of hard links is that it's much more lightweight solution. Using deduplication on ZFS requires lots of processing power & memory, and writing large amounts of data is much slower.

ZFS deduplication is per-block, so one (rare) advantage is, if 2 large files are almost similar, much of their contents might still get successfully deduplicated.

Obviously the main advantage of deduplication is that once enabled, it's fully automatic.

If you go ZFS deduplication route, I'd recommend creating at least 2 pools, one with deduplication (only for data you consider worthy deduplicating) and another for everything else. All extra data in dedup zfs pool hurts performance further.